# Can webpack-dev-server watch for changes and write on filesystem for iisexpress?

Tags: javascript, iis, webpack, vue.js, devops

A big ASP.NET MVC application serves on :80. A part of it that is written in vue. Currently we are running a manual "npm run build" after each change. It takes too long.

**webpack-dev-server seems as the perfect solution**. It watches for change and caches in memory! But it will conflict with iisexpress. [There are no easy solutions making them work together.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318684/how-to-get-webpack-and-iis-express-to-work-together)

I think I have a better idea:

1. When starting to work **"npm run start"** setups webpack-dev-server for the vue parts from "./src/vue/". Serving all of the "localhost:8080/dist/bundle.[chunk].js".
2. When changes are made in any of the files in "./src/vue/" on save **"npm run refresh"** is being ran. A small script that requests all chunks "localhost:8080/dist/.[chunk].js" and places in "./dist/".
3. Developer F5s our ASP.NET MVC app and iisexpress serves the updated "./dist/".

My question is **how do I request all of the chunks easily both for .js and .css files** from webpack-dev-server?

I could have to write out the output from the first "npm run start" into a config file which is then read by "npm run refresh". Is this even reasonable? I hoped webpack-dev-server could write to file system itself.

---

Hot-module-reloading would be nice, but the ASP app is a mess of iframes. Currently just trying make our build process a little faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anybody finds this thread:

The answer was to use webpack --watch! Does exactly what I described and without the mess.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/